# Matlab Using ode45 for 4th order ode

Tags: matlab

```
y'''' + (a1 + a2*v(t)^2)*y'' + (a3 + a4*v(t)^2)*y = 0 
y(0) = 2, Dy(0) = 0, D2y(0) = 0, D3y(0) = 0
```

I tried to solve the above 4th order ode with Matlab's `dsolve` but the results I got were very large. As I now understand, `dsolve` will not work here, I will have to use `ode45` to solve this equation.

I tried to follow Matlab's document on [ode45](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) but I couldn't understand it completely. Moreover, in my case, the coefficients are also time dependent.

How can I convert this equation in format understandable by `ode45`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a 4th order ODE, you can't solve that directly. You must rewrite that as a system of first-order ODEs:

```
y_3' = -(a1+a2*v(t))*y_2 - (a3+a4*v(t)^2)*y
y_2' = y_3
y_1' = y_2
y' = y_1
```

with

```
y(0) = 2
y_1(0) = 0
y_2(0) = 0
y_3(0) = 0
```

This, you can feed to ODE45...